# Как запарсить массив для формирования pach

Tags: php, рекурсия

Не могу разобраться нужно получить массив который бы парсил pach категорий под категорий и тог далее... Зарание глубина вложенности не известна поэтому хотел сделать через рекурсию но что то не получается. Входные данные в Функцию:

```
    array(6) {
  [0]=&gt;
  array(3) {
    ["id"]=&gt;
    string(2) "11"
    ["text"]=&gt;
    string(18) "Смартфоны"
    ["id_parent"]=&gt;
    string(1) "0"
  }
  [1]=&gt;
  array(3) {
    ["id"]=&gt;
    string(2) "12"
    ["text"]=&gt;
    string(5) "Aplle"
    ["id_parent"]=&gt;
    string(2) "11"
  }
  [2]=&gt;
  array(3) {
    ["id"]=&gt;
    string(2) "13"
    ["text"]=&gt;
    string(6) "Xiaomi"
    ["id_parent"]=&gt;
    string(2) "11"
  }
  [3]=&gt;
  array(3) {
    ["id"]=&gt;
    string(2) "14"
    ["text"]=&gt;
    string(6) "Huawei"
    ["id_parent"]=&gt;
    string(1) "0"
  }
  [4]=&gt;
  array(3) {
    ["id"]=&gt;
    string(2) "15"
    ["text"]=&gt;
    string(37) "Зарядные устройства"
    ["id_parent"]=&gt;
    string(1) "0"
  }
  [5]=&gt;
  array(3) {
    ["id"]=&gt;
    string(2) "16"
    ["text"]=&gt;
    string(8) "Шлак"
    ["id_parent"]=&gt;
    string(2) "12"
  }
}
```

Сама функция

```
private static function recursive($data, $pid = 0, $path = "", $level = 0, $arr = []) {

    foreach ($data as $row) { //перебираем строки
        if ($row['id_parent'] == $pid) { //Начинаем со строк, pid которых передан в функцию, у нас это 0, т.е. корень сайта

            //Собираем строку в ассоциативный массив
            $_row['id'] = $row['id'];
            $_row['text'] = $path . "/" . $row['text'];

            $arr[] = $_row; //Прибавляем каждую строку к выходному массиву
            //Строка обработана, теперь запустим эту же функцию для текущего uid, то есть
            //пойдёт обратотка дочерней строки (у которой этот uid является pid-ом)
            self::recursive($data, $row['id'], $_row['text'], $level + 1, $arr);
        }
    }
    var_dump($arr);
}
```

на выходе получаю через var_dump

```
    array(0) {
}
array(1) {
  [0]=&gt;
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=&gt;
    string(2) "16"
    ["text"]=&gt;
    string(34) "/Смартфоны/Aplle/Шлак"
  }
}
array(0) {
}
array(2) {
  [0]=&gt;
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=&gt;
    string(2) "12"
    ["text"]=&gt;
    string(25) "/Смартфоны/Aplle"
  }
  [1]=&gt;
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=&gt;
    string(2) "13"
    ["text"]=&gt;
    string(26) "/Смартфоны/Xiaomi"
  }
}
array(0) {
}
array(0) {
}
array(3) {
  [0]=&gt;
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=&gt;
    string(2) "11"
    ["text"]=&gt;
    string(19) "/Смартфоны"
  }
  [1]=&gt;
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=&gt;
    string(2) "14"
    ["text"]=&gt;
    string(7) "/Huawei"
  }
  [2]=&gt;
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=&gt;
    string(2) "15"
    ["text"]=&gt;
    string(38) "/Зарядные устройства"
  }
}
```

То есть судя из результата массив переопределяется и если вернуть return $arr то получим не все значения

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В определении функции 5 аргументов. В вызове - 4. Вы массив $arr не передаёте в рекурсию - как могут в нём накапливаться данные.

А когда будете передавать, то его надо и возвращать из рекурсии как результат функции recursive(). А вардампить в том месте, откуда вы вызываете функцию в первый раз, вне её.

UPDATE:

Такой код работает

```
<?php

$data = array(
    0 => array(
        'id'        => '11',
        'text'      => 'Смартфоны',
        'id_parent' => '0',
    ),
    1 => array(
        'id'        => '12',
        'text'      => 'Apple',
        'id_parent' => '11',
    ),
    2 =>
        array(
            'id'        => '13',
            'text'      => 'Xiaomi',
            'id_parent' => '11',
        ),
    3 =>
        array(
            'id'        => '14',
            'text'      => 'Huawei',
            'id_parent' => '0',
        ),
    4 =>
        array(
            'id'        => '15',
            'text'      => 'Зарядные устройства',
            'id_parent' => '0',
        ),
    5 =>
        array(
            'id'        => '16',
            'text'      => 'Шлак',
            'id_parent' => '12',
        ),
);

function recursive( $data, $pid = 0, $path = '', $level = 0, $arr = [] ) {

    foreach ( $data as $row ) { //перебираем строки
        if ( $row['id_parent'] == $pid ) { //Начинаем со строк, pid которых передан в функцию, у нас это 0, т.е. корень сайта

            //Собираем строку в ассоциативный массив
            $_row['id']   = $row['id'];
            $_row['text'] = $path . '/' . $row['text'];

            $arr[] = $_row; //Прибавляем каждую строку к выходному массиву
            //Строка обработана, теперь запустим эту же функцию для текущего uid, то есть
            //пойдёт обратотка дочерней строки (у которой этот uid является pid-ом)
            $arr = recursive( $data, $row['id'], $_row['text'], $level + 1, $arr );
        }
    }

    return $arr;
}

var_dump( recursive( $data ) );
```

Результат:

```
array(6) {
    [0]=>
  array(2) {
        ["id"]=>
    string(2) "11"
        ["text"]=>
    string(19) "/Смартфоны"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
        ["id"]=>
    string(2) "12"
        ["text"]=>
    string(25) "/Смартфоны/Apple"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
        ["id"]=>
    string(2) "16"
        ["text"]=>
    string(34) "/Смартфоны/Apple/Шлак"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
        ["id"]=>
    string(2) "13"
        ["text"]=>
    string(26) "/Смартфоны/Xiaomi"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(2) {
        ["id"]=>
    string(2) "14"
        ["text"]=>
    string(7) "/Huawei"
  }
  [5]=>
  array(2) {
        ["id"]=>
    string(2) "15"
        ["text"]=>
    string(38) "/Зарядные устройства"
  }
}
```

Comment: А можете привести пример return? где он должен возвращать?. 5 - аргумент начал передавать.

Comment: Вообще затея у меня в том что хочу сделать что то типа /Смартфон/Apple/Шлак/Что то еще/и так далее

Comment: Мне трудно переписать функцию, не видя данных. Дайте какой-то пример.

Comment: Добрый день. Внес изменения.

Comment: вы не смотрели? получиться или нет что то с этим сделать?

Comment: не было времени. сейчас сделаю

Comment: Я обновил ответ 4 часа назад)